# PDF interaction with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I want to display a PDF and make the user interact with it. Specifically I want:

- Show a PDF
- That the user can click on the PDF (with long tap for example) and add a mark. I want this mark to be a personalized image.
- Capture the event when a user taps on one of these marks.
- I want these marks to be recoverable. That is, I want to recover the pdf coordinates where these marks are to be able to save them and retrieve them at another time.

I have looked for solutions like `PDFTron` or `PDFKit` but  I can't find the way to satisfy these requirements. Is there any way to satisfy this requirements with these solutions or other solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about iOS Development in Swift, I have used these libraries before and I would definitely recommend these:

Open Source:

1. [LazyPDFKit](https://github.com/lazyprogram/LazyPDFKit)

- Show a PDF ✅
- Supports Basic PDF annotation (But no image) ✅
- Event Listener/Delegate ✅
- Recoverable/Undoable ✅

2. [TPPDF](https://github.com/techprimate/TPPDF)

   - Show a PDF ✅
   - Supports Basic PDF annotation ‍♂️
   - Event Listener/Delegate ✅
   - Recoverable/Undoable ✅

However, if you have some money to spend:

3. [PSPDFKIT](https://pspdfkit.com/pdf-sdk/ios/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=paid_search&utm_campaign=ios&utm_content=broad&utm_term=pdf%20ios%20library&gclid=CjwKCAjw_JuGBhBkEiwA1xmbRXB4E-NcSHekqjiBl08sPHzzRStEtvg3Q4juet9dy3uMMBhclNzvyhoC49sQAvD_BwE)

- Everything related to PDF ✅

P.S. If you just need to annotate a PDF [PDFDrawingView](https://github.com/jrosen081/PDFDrawingView) would be enough.